# Calling a function using onclick, and within that function calling another function using onclick

Tags: javascript, css, onclick

I am trying to call a function using onclick, but this function is already inside another function that is called via onclick.

I actually want to go on doing this for about 6-7 times.

The code might help in reducing the confusion:

The HTML+JS:

```
{
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

function abc()
{
    document.getElementById("first").className='disc';
    document.getElementById("first").onClick="def();";
}
function def()
{
    document.getElementById("first").className='disco';
}

</script>
<input type="button" value="Change Color of this text" id="first" class="" onclick="abc();">
</body>

}
```

The CSS:

```
.disc 
{
    color: red;
}
.disco
{
    color: yellow;
}
```

I want to change the color of the text in the button every time the user clicks on it. So what is the problem? It just changes to red, but not to yellow when I click over it once more.

Comment: Where do you see the code that will change it to back yellow? I do not see any.

Comment: Why not just use hover in your css?

Comment: It will NOT change it BACK to yellow.

It will first be black, when first click, it will change to red, when second click, it should turn to yellow. That is what I want

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you according to your requirement in comment:-

Javascript

```
function abc(){
    if(document.getElementById("first").className == "" || document.getElementById("first").className == "disco"){
        document.getElementById("first").className = "disc";
    }
    else if(document.getElementById("first").className=="disc"){
        document.getElementById("first").className="disco";
    }    
}
```

You need not to change anything in HTML & css.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the function from abc() to def(), which I'm not sure you can do something like that.. Why don't you just use 1 function and check the current className, like below code:

```
function abc()
{
    if(document.getElementById("first").className == "disco" || document.getElementById("first").className == "") //change from red to yellow
       document.getElementById("first").className="disc";
    else //change from yellow to red
       document.getElementById("first").className="disco"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var first = document.getElementById("first"), counter = 0;
first.addEventListener('click', function () {
    first.className = (counter % 2) ?  'disc' : 'disco';
    counter +=1;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fNW23/

fixed code and more reliable solution.